# Get PID from open Excel file

Tags: excel, powershell

Is there a way to get the pid of an Excel process that has opened a specific file and set that pid in a variable like "FilePID"?

Kinda like:

```
Get-Process -name EXCEL file:"C:\Excel\file.xlsx" -> $FilePID
```

Comment: `$FilePID = (Get-Process -name Excel | Where-Object { $_.MainWindowTitle -like 'yourfilename.xlsx*' }).Id`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you know the name of the opened file in Excel you could do this:

```
$FilePID = (Get-Process -name Excel | Where-Object { $_.MainWindowTitle -like 'yourfilename.xlsx*' }).Id
```

Usually, Excel shows something like `yourfilename.xlsx - Excel` in its title bar, so that is the reason for the trailing wildcard character `*`

Comment: This works perfect!! Thanks a lot Theo! But it only works with "$Excel.visible = $true". If I use "$false" it's not working. Is there a workaround for this?

Comment: @ASD For that I guess you need to write some C# code to use the `GetWindowText` from user32.dll Haven't worked that out yet..

Comment: You know what... I guess most of the other things i tried didn't work because of "$false". Incredible......

Comment: @ASD Yep.. I just did some investigation with Excel opening a file while `$Excel.visible = $false` and it turns out that in such a case Excel does not fill the `.MainWindowTitle` and even sets the `.MainWindowHandle` to `0`, so I don't think it is possible..